# Why does SSRS paste objects in random locations in reports?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Whenever I copy-paste in an SSRS report I am bemused by where the object copied will appear. Can someone explain this?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with SSRS but I know there's something related to setting the position of objects through Properties window. You can set them relative to the edges of the report. You can check this first, I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When cutting and pasting items in the report designer, SSRS will paste the item **dead center** in the parent item, no matter how you're pasting. This is probably reasonable for `Ctrl+V`, since it has no location context really, but a bit weird if your pasting with the right-click context menu.

You can see this pretty easily in an isolated test. Say I have a textbox in the bottom right of the report body, which is so nice I want to past it in the bottom left as well:

[image]

[image]

Here's the end result:

[image]

Dead center. Nothing like we wanted, but at least it's there.

This is in the report body - if you were pasting into a rectangle, the item would be pasted dead center in that rectangle:

[image]

So there is consistency to where the item will appear - by design, always in the center of the parent item - hopefully this leaves you a little less bemused. While consistent, whether this is actual *reasonable* behaviour I guess is a moot point.

Comment: Mind. Blown. This was always particularly weird in large reports with no rectangles that were very wide. This explains why. Dead center was in the middle of nowhere! Thanks, I can now sleep well at night.